# Scrapy HtmlXPathSelector

Tags: scrapy

Just trying out scrapy and trying to get a basic spider working.  I know this is just probably something I'm missing but I've tried everything I can think of.

The error I get is:

```
line 11, in JustASpider
    sites = hxs.select('//title/text()')
NameError: name 'hxs' is not defined
```

My code is very basic at the moment, but I still can't seem to find where I'm going wrong. Thanks for any help!

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class JustASpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "google.com"
    start_urls = ["http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=search"]


    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//title/text()')
        for site in sites:
            print site.extract()


SPIDER = JustASpider()
```

Comment: How do you run your spider? `scrapy crawl "google.com"`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code (aside from not needing to declare SPIDER anymore), it works for me.

Comment: @Leo That's how I've been running it.

Comment: What output do you get from "`scrapy version -v`" on the command line?

Comment: @stav Scrapy  : 0.14.4
Twisted : 12.1.0
Python  : 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) - [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
Platform: Darwin-10.8.0-i386-64bit

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Scrapy, try renaming `hxs` to something else which is a kind way of saying that your indentation is probably mixed with tabs and spaces, like warwaruk says.  Retype everything by hand.

Comment: @stav That's essentially what I did, checked to see that it was all tabs.  So I honestly have no idea what happened, but I think it may have been something to do with the for loop. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Why don't you just response.xpath('//title/text()').extract() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I removed the SPIDER call at the end and removed the for loop.  There was only one title tag (as one would expect) and it seems that was throwing off the loop.  The code I have working is as follows:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class JustASpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "google.com"
    start_urls = ["http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=search"]


    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//title/text()')
        final = titles.extract()
```

Comment: your code works, but it's better to use a simple name for the spiders, like "google" or "googleSpider" instead of "google.com"

Answer (score 7):

The code looks quite old version. I recommend using these codes instead

```html
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class JustASpider(Spider):
    name = "googlespider"
    allowed_domains=["google.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=search"]


    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        print sites
        #for site in sites: (I dont know why you want to loop for extracting the text in the title element)
            #print site.extract()
```

hope it helps and [here](https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot/blob/master/dirbot/spiders/dmoz.py) is a good example to follow.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, `NameError: name 'hxs' is not defined`, and the problem related to spaces and tabs: the IDE uses spaces instead of tabs, you should check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Code looks correct.

In latest versions of Scrapy
HtmlXPathSelector is deprecated.
Use Selector:

```
hxs = Selector(response)
sites = hxs.xpath('//title/text()')
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are running the code you are showing us.

Try deleting `*.pyc` files in your project.

Comment: After deleting all the pyc files in the folder, I'm still getting the same error. If I was missing a dependency, would I be getting an import error?

Comment: plese check indentation in you code. maybe you mixing tabs with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. Save the file as `test.py`
2. Use the command `scrapy runspider <filename.py>`

For example:

```
scrapy runspider test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just a demo but it works. need to be customized offcourse.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
        for site in sites:
            title = site.select('a/text()').extract()
            link = site.select('a/@href').extract()
            desc = site.select('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
```

into

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
```

And use `hxs=Selector(response)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use Scrapy with BeautifulSoup4.0. For me, Soup is easy to read and understand. This is an option if you don't have to use HtmlXPathSelector. Hope this helps!

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import Item

def parse(self, response):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body,'html.parser')
    print 'Current url: %s' % response.url
    item = Item()
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if link.get('href') is not None:
            url = response.urljoin(link.get('href'))
            item['url'] = url
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)
            yield item
```